# Some columns not visualizing for a time series of treatment and control in forest and field research site

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, scatter-plot, boxplot

I have been trying to look at some soil data that I've collected from forest and field sites that have undergone either a biological treatment (T), or a conventional control (C). This information was collected over time, and the data from some columns are displaying, but not others.

Here is my code (data follows):

```
# Load packages for data visualization

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Remove NAs from dataframe
C4Data <- na.omit(C4Data)
sum(is.na(C4Data))

# Data Summary

summary_stats <- C4Data %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  summarize(
    Mean_BacBio = mean(ifelse(is.numeric(BacBio), BacBio, NA)),
    Mean_FunBio = mean(ifelse(is.numeric(FunBio), FunBio, NA)),
    Mean_Com = mean(ifelse(is.numeric(Com), Com, NA)),
    Mean_STAB = mean(ifelse(is.numeric(STAB), STAB, NA))
  )

print(summary_stats)
```

**FIRST PROBLEM - Com and STAB data are not appearing in summary statistics.
It looks to me like it doesn't think there are any values, but there are!**

```
# Box plots for BacBio, FunBio, F:B, Com, and STAB
ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Type, y = BacBio)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "BacBio by Treatment Type")

ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Type, y = Com)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "Compaction by Treatment Type")

ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Type, y = STAB)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "Ag Stability by Treatment Type")
```

**SECOND PROBLEM - Com and STAB data are appearing, but in the strangest looking boxplot I've ever seen. Weird.**

```
# Check the differences between treatment and control

t_test_resultBacBio <- t.test(BacBio ~ Type, data = C4Data)
print(t_test_resultBacBio)

t_test_resultCom <- t.test(Com ~ Type, data = C4Data)
print(t_test_resultCom)

t_test_resultSTAB <- t.test(STAB ~ Type, data = C4Data)
print(t_test_resultSTAB)
```

**THIRD PROBLEM: For Com and STAB data, I'm getting an NA error, even though I have asked R to ignore NAs. **

```
# Group the data by 'Type' (Treatment/Control) and 'Land' (Forest/Field)
grouped_data <- C4Data %>%
  group_by(Type, Land)

# Calculate summary statistics (mean, SD, etc.) for 'FunBio' and 'BacBio'
summary_stats <- grouped_data %>%
  summarize(
    Mean_FunBio = mean(FunBio, na.rm = TRUE),
    SD_FunBio = sd(FunBio, na.rm = TRUE),
    Mean_BacBio = mean(BacBio, na.rm = TRUE),
    SD_BacBio = sd(BacBio, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

print(summary_stats)

# Impute missing values with the mean of the non-missing values
C4Data <- C4Data %>%
  group_by(Land, Type) %>%
  mutate(
    FunBio = ifelse(is.na(FunBio), mean(FunBio, na.rm = TRUE), FunBio),
    BacBio = ifelse(is.na(BacBio), mean(BacBio, na.rm = TRUE), BacBio)
  )


# Create a plot to visualize the differences
ggplot(summary_stats, aes(x = Land, y = Mean_FunBio, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(
    title = "Comparison of FunBio by Land and Type",
    y = "Mean FunBio",
    fill = "Type"
  )
```

## TIME SERIES

```
# Group the data by 'Land' (Forest/Field), 'Type' (Treatment/Control), and 'Date'
grouped_data <- C4Data %>%
  group_by(Land, Type, Date)

# Calculate summary statistics (mean) for 'FunBio' and 'BacBio'
summary_stats <- grouped_data %>%
  summarize(
    Mean_FunBio = mean(FunBio, na.rm = TRUE),
    Mean_BacBio = mean(BacBio, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

# Scatterplots of all data

# Create a scatterplot of 'FunBio' by 'Land' and 'Type'
ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Date, y = FunBio, color = Land, linetype = Type)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Scatterplot of FunBio by Land and Type",
    x = "Date",
    y = "FunBio"
  )
```

**FOURTH PROBLEM: The dates for the time series are out of order, and I'd like the labels to be more readable**

```
# Scatterplots including differences between treatment and control

# Create a scatterplot of 'FunBio' by 'Land' and 'Type' with different shapes
ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Date, y = FunBio, color = Land, shape = Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +  # You can adjust the size of the points as needed
  labs(
    title = "Scatterplot of FunBio by Land and Type",
    x = "Date",
    y = "FunBio"
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Treatment" = 1, "Control" = 16)) +  # Define shapes for 
Treatment and Control
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title = "Type"))

# Create a scatterplot with a custom shape for missing values
ggplot(C4Data, aes(x = Date, y = FunBio, color = Land, shape = Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  labs(
    title = "Scatterplot of FunBio by Land and Type",
    x = "Date",
    y = "FunBio"
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Treatment" = 1, "Control" = 16, "na" = NA)) +  # Define shapes
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title = "Type"))
```

**FIFTH PROBLEM: No data appears on the time series graph that differentiates between Land Use and Treatment.**

```
    > dput(C4Data)
    structure(list(Sample = c("R1S4", "R1S5", "R2S1", "R2S3", "R3S1", 
"R3S5", "R4S4", "R4S6", "R5S3", "R5S6", "R6S2", "R6S6", "R7S2", 
"R7S5", "R8S5", "R8S6", "R1S2", "R1S6", "R2S2", "R2S6", "R3S4", 
"R3S6", "R4S4", "R4S5", "R5S1", "R5S5", "R6S5", "R6S6", "R7S1", 
"R7S5", "R8S1", "R8S3", "R1S3", "R1S6", "R2S6", "R2S5", "R3S3", 
"R3S5", "R4S2", "R4S4", "R5S2", "R5S4", "R6S1", "R6S2", "R7S4", 
"R7S5", "R8S2", "R8S6", "R1S3", "R1S4", "R2S3", "R2S5", "R3S5", 
"R3S6", "R4S1", "R4S3", "R5S2", "R5S3", "R6S2", "R6S5", "R7S2", 
"R7S4", "R8S3", "R8S4", "R1S1", "R1S6", "R2S3", "R2S4", "R3S4", 
"R3S5", "R4S3", "R4S6", "R5S1", "R5S2", "R6S1", "R6S2", "R7S5", 
"R7S6", "R8S4", "R8S5", "R1S3", "R1S4", "R2S4", "R2S5", "R3S4", 
"R3S6", "R4S4", "R4S6", "R5S1", "R5S4", "R6S1", "R6S2", "R7S2", 
"R7S3", "R8S3", "R8S5", "R1S1", "R1S2", "R2S6", "R2S5", "R3S1", 
"R3S6", "R4S1", "R4S5", "R5S5", "R5S6", "R6S2", "R6S5", "R7S1", 
"R7S3", "R8S2", "R8S3", "R1S2", "R1S6", "R2S1", "R2S3", "R3S2", 
"R3S5", "R4S3", "R4S5", "R5S4", "R5S6", "R6S2", "R6S5", "R7S4", 
"R7S5", "R8S2", "R8S4", "R2S1", "R3S1", "R3S2", "R4S2", "R2S3", 
"R3S3", "R1S4", "R2S4", "R2S5", "R3S5", "R1S6", "R4S6", "R5S1", 
"R8S1", "R6S2", "R7S2", "R7S3", "R8S3", "R6S4", "R7S4", "R5S5", 
"R6S5", "R6S6", "R7S6"), Row = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
7L), Sec = c(4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), Loc = c("BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", 
"BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "BG777", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", 
"PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG", "PreRG"), Land = c("Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", 
"Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Forest", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", "Field", 
"Field", "Field", "Field"), Type = c("C", "C", "T", "T", "C", 
"C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", 
"T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", 
"T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", 
"C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", 
"C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", 
"T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", 
"T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", 
"C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", 
"C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", 
"T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", 
"T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "C", "T", "T", "C", "C", "T", "T", "C", 
"C", "T", "T", "C"), Date = c("13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", 
"13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", 
"13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", 
"13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "13-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", 
"27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", 
"27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", 
"27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "27-Jun-23", "11-Jul-23", 
"11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", 
"11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", 
"11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", "11-Jul-23", 
"25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", 
"25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", 
"25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", "25-Jul-23", 
"25-Jul-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", 
"08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", 
"08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", 
"08-Aug-23", "08-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", 
"22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", 
"22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", 
"22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "22-Aug-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", 
"05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", 
"05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", 
"05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "05-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", 
"19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", 
"19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", 
"19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", "19-Sep-23", 
"03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", 
"03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", 
"03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", 
"03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", 
"03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23", "03-Oct-23"), BacBio = c(3856.33, 
3605.51, 6320.61, 1371.66, 1724.37, 1733.78, 4401.86, 1401.45, 
854.35, 431.09, 859.05, 1053.44, 1166.3, 1285.44, 1749.46, 1379.5, 
1227.69, 2072.55, 2392.67, 3399.24, 2904.21, 1650.12, 3267.23, 
379.53, 1458.7, 1293.69, 1320.09, 1089.08, 1729.32, 963.67, 1650.12, 
1247.49, 2269.9, 2545.8, 1404.58, 1511.18, 1843.51, 1818.43, 
1536.26, 1893.68, 833.97, 435.8, 1247.82, 1216.47, 1536.26, 1323.06, 
1191.39, 790.08, 2224.36, 3768.87, 1986.74, 2547.78, 3042.82, 
2567.58, 3960.28, 4574.13, 818.46, 2085.75, 2138.55, 2626.99, 
2798.6, 1610.52, 2805.2, 2310.17, 576.88, 1990.87, 4671.49, 8182.94, 
2806.03, 1667.94, 2163.31, 838.67, 953.11, 1417.12, 1542.53, 
1034.62, 1567.61, 1385.77, 1316.79, 1567.61, 5079.06, 4075.79, 
7775.36, 4608.78, 3605.51, 5831.52, 12164.67, 2501.91, 2690.02, 
1266.63, 8151.59, 2708.83, 1504.91, 689.75, 1363.82, 1120.84, 
9129.78, 7374.05, 11061.07, 8628.14, 9681.57, 3818.7, 11192.75, 
5317.34, 2188.39, 877.86, 1768.27, 3323.34, 7712.65, 1881.14, 
1410.85, 1332.47, 4796.89, 1865.46, 6207.75, 6678.03, 7744.01, 
1128.68, 4232.55, 7399.13, 244.55, 971.92, 1003.27, 1473.56, 
4514.72, 1222.74, 2900.08, 1881.14, 3937.84, 6094.88, 476.55, 
7424.21, 3687.02, 2583.43, 4589.97, 9179.94, 6019.63, 7336.43, 
2229.15, 2332.61, 4564.89, 8013.64, 2301.26, 1912.49, 1843.51, 
2282.44, 2508.18, 2809.16, 2169.58, 5235.83, 3116.41, 4740.46
), ActBio = c(2.51, 2.02, 0.87, 1.04, 0.72, 1.74, 2, 1.81, 2.87, 
1.89, 1.34, 2.27, 1.66, 1.91, 1.42, 0.77, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2, 1.29, 
0.74, 0.46, 1.99, 0.22, 0.99, 1.71, 1.55, 3.08, 0.66, 1.21, 0.42, 
1.55, 0.77, 0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0.29, 0.38, 0, 0.23, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 
0.16, 0, 0, 0.41, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.23, 0.16, 0, 0.26, 0.15, 0.13, 
0.13, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0.14, 0, 0, 0, 0.26, 0.26, 0.11, 
0.06, 0, 0.28, 0, 0, 0, 0.61, 0, 0.13, 0.14, 0, 0.16, 0, 0, 0, 
0.72, 0, 0.32, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.18, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.57, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FunBio = c(531.63, 708.52, 434.98, 
379.64, 778.98, 728.19, 514.52, 1073.11, 229.37, 362.34, 129.28, 
517.23, 358.03, 187.64, 170.37, 201.55, 673.11, 423.53, 472, 
750.9, 761.53, 96.65, 932.34, 683.64, 0, 257.9, 124.42, 594.31, 
307.41, 153.96, 46.66, 64.22, 46.05, 288.98, 518.09, 139.15, 
313.32, 177.1, 1002.77, 466.46, 70.36, 94.68, 188.13, 44.32, 
66.57, 192.95, 23.52, 104.22, 384.48, 869.49, 1193.18, 453.64, 
230.47, 472.78, 305.63, 251.91, 45.62, 35.86, 114.52, 88.54, 
5.68, 51.97, 113.62, 312.94, 46.54, 206.27, 387.74, 180.49, 358.69, 
181.38, 798.27, 838.02, 352.18, 1.66, 177.07, 124.1, 136.07, 
60.13, 209.28, 809.71, 64.61, 122.92, 259.64, 59.94, 176.5, 66.63, 
52.53, 48.35, 127.39, 5.91, 86.99, 115.24, 33.36, 105.06, 122.79, 
46.95, 76.97, 15.05, 116.95, 172.2, 12.87, 71.71, 74.92, 75.64, 
107.9, 23.56, 210.12, 15.11, 2.99, 3.99, 138.18, 38.09, 288.47, 
76.97, 324.51, 241.55, 108.88, 131.06, 405.61, 133.47, 69.58, 
108.07, 52.89, 56.13, 12.35, 67.97, 71.76, 70.94, 2298.42, 199.95, 
316.99, 471.97, 1742.64, 88.5, 253.45, 370.47, 817.36, 119.67, 
582.85, 2890.18, 83.33, 392.11, 492.8, 77.2, 68.62, 65.01, 283.09, 
41.37, 86.41, 134.73, 698.07, 38.09), FB = c(0.14, 0.2, 0.07, 
0.28, 0.45, 0.42, 0.12, 0.76, 0.27, 0.84, 0.15, 0.49, 0.31, 0.15, 
0.1, 0.15, 0.55, 0.2, 0.2, 0.22, 0.26, 0.06, 0.29, 1.8, 0, 0.2, 
0.09, 0.54, 0.18, 0.16, 0.03, 0.05, 0.02, 0.11, 0.37, 0.09, 0.17, 
0.1, 0.65, 0.25, 0.08, 0.22, 0.15, 0.04, 0.04, 0.15, 0.02, 0.13, 
0.17, 0.23, 0.6, 0.18, 0.08, 0.18, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.02, 0.05, 
0.03, 0, 0.03, 0.04, 0.14, 0.08, 0.1, 0.08, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 
0.37, 1, 0.37, 0, 0.11, 0.12, 0.09, 0.04, 0.16, 0.52, 0.01, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0, 0.01, 0.04, 0.02, 0.15, 
0.09, 0.04, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 
0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.03, 0.06, 0.04, 0.05, 0.04, 0.01, 0.12, 
0.1, 0.02, 0.28, 0.11, 0.05, 0.04, 0, 0.06, 0.02, 0.04, 0.58, 
0.03, 0.67, 0.06, 0.47, 0.03, 0.06, 0.04, 0.14, 0.02, 0.26, 1.24, 
0.02, 0.05, 0.21, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.11, 0.01, 0.04, 0.03, 0.22, 
0.01), Proto = c(23224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46448, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23224, 
0, 0, 23224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24446.2, 0, 0, 24446.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 13037.97, 16297.47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13037.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 17030.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27868.67, 0, 13934.33, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12386.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 12386.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 
0, 13934.33, 10837.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 0, 10837.82, 
0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 0, 13934.33, 0, 0, 0, 13934.33, 0, 13934.33, 
41803, 13934.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Flag = c(23224, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 23224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13037.97, 16297.47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
13037.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17030.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 27868.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
12386.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12386.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 13934.33, 10837.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 0, 13934.33, 0, 0, 0, 
13934.33, 0, 13934.33, 41803, 13934.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Amoe = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23224, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24446.2, 0, 0, 24446.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13934.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10837.82, 0, 
0, 10837.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BfNem = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 285L, 0L, 285L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 300L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 190L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 190L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 160L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 160L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 190L, 0L, 0L, 190L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 133L, 0L, 0L, 133L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 342L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 171L, 0L, 171L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 171L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FfNem = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 285L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 190L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PNem = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Oom = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 67.59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cili = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), RfNem = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 300L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Com = c("46", "59", "51", "47", "41", "54", "69", 
"32", "71", "64", "67", "67", "60", "66", "48", "52", "40", "33", 
"41", "38", "37", "32", "37", "39", "34", "35", "45", "38", "30", 
"38", "40", "41", "39", "42", "53", "35", "45", "47", "37", "39", 
"36", "43", "39", "46", "38", "43", "47", "59", "28", "36", "41", 
"53", "40", "38", "36", "42", "29", "32", "33", "38", "33", "39", 
"40", "44", "25", "31", "36", "37", "25", "26", "40", "36", "26", 
"37", "32", "35", "36", "31", "42", "32", "39", "32", "39", "51", 
"38", "37", "49", "32", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", 
"na", "31", "46", "63", "67", "48", "34", "48", "68", "35", "33", 
"42", "39", "31", "27", "39", "42", "36", "35", "50", "38", "32", 
"37", "40", "43", "39", "34", "36", "38", "34", "32", "35", "54", 
"53", "43", "49", "47", "46", "47", "39", "52", "57", "51", "45", 
"37", "24", "26", "35", "42", "32", "32", "55", "33", "36", "40", 
"47", "34"), STAB = c("0.541", "0.605", "0.644", "0.604", "0.644", 
"0.567", "0.583", "0.67", "0.595", "0.528", "0.613", "0.717", 
"0.578", "0.703", "0.654", "0.584", "0.604", "0.662", "na", "0.619", 
"0.602", "0.765", "0.496", "0.44", "0.708", "0.664", "0.663", 
"0.676", "0.542", "0.605", "0.689", "0.689", "0.638", "0.631", 
"0.715", "0.58", "0.561", "0.631", "0.705", "0.579", "0.702", 
"0.662", "0.626", "0.591", "0.652", "0.663", "0.756", "0.554", 
"0.387", "0.531", "0.548", "0.465", "0.42", "0.489", "0.393", 
"0.538", "0.522", "0.39", "0.451", "0.361", "0.407", "0.485", 
"0.484", "0.506", "0.373", "0.49", "0.536", "0.41", "0.451", 
"0.439", "0.513", "0.568", "0.536", "0.495", "0.493", "0.602", 
"0.512", "0.634", "0.567", "0.531", "0.520343567", "0.492081267", 
"0.476002967", "0.452843267", "0.4364572", "0.466684433", "0.367977867", 
"0.5558608", "0.472848533", "0.653652533", "0.480223267", "0.6302153", 
"0.477811867", "0.521436967", "0.4972648", "0.697138533", "0.384874333", 
"0.4885639", "0.4575349", "0.378476867", "0.365335233", "0.418678933", 
"0.4300512", "0.4059196", "0.616009567", "0.6516018", "0.592206467", 
"0.422982233", "0.4311655", "0.390189167", "0.480162067", "0.475153633", 
"0.5911627", "0.568247733", "0.538104767", "0.502267333", "0.599456567", 
"0.519115667", "0.620787167", "0.485490867", "0.679130967", "0.672020433", 
"0.725440633", "0.563664067", "0.4876092", "0.641354167", "0.638149633", 
"0.66966", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", 
"na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", 
"na", "na", "na", "na")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-152L))
```

Comment: `C4Data$Com` and `C4Data$STAB` are loaded as character (text) data. (What's the standard deviation of "orange" and "whale"?) Try `C4Data$Com <- as.numeric(C4Data$Com)` or `C4Data$Com <- readr::parse_number(C4Data$Com)`

Comment: Similarly, "22-Aug-23" doesn't have a Date type -- it's no different from "EBH" or "cat." `C4Data$Date <- as.Date(C4Data$Date, "%d-%b-%y")` should convert those strings to R's Date type, which will plot chronologically.

Comment: Use `str(C4Data)` to review what types your data uses.

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring! Those suggestions solved the first four problems. I'm still struggling with #5 if anyone has any ideas

Comment: Your Types are "C" and "T" but your shape specifications are for "Control" and "Treatment."

Comment: Thank you!!! Feels like a silly miss on my part. Much appreciated